# How to simulate XSS in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-core, xss

I want a simple method to simulate XSS attack.

I've created asp.net core 5.0 mvc, then added a controller:

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    public string Welcome(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then launched /helloworld/welcome?name=<script>alert("hello")</script>, expecting to display alert, but it displays it as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to explicitly execute this, you need to tell the view engine to do so:

```
public IActionResult Index(string name)
{
    ViewBag.name = name;
    return View();
}

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.name)
```

Without it, asp.net core would encode it, and then display it as a string, because it is a string. You are explicitly returning a string in your code.